# Conflict between DataTables SearchBuilder and Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, momentjs

I have just started using the SearchBuilder. Before that, I was using Moment.js (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js) and DateTime Moment (https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/sorting/datetime-moment.js).

When using the Searchbuilder for dates, I am getting the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function**.

Is any solution available?

Link to test case: https://jsfiddle.net/jL7pt01w/1/

My code:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm');
            var table = $('#' + panel.id).find('#operatorLogs').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                fixedHeader: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                stateSave: false,
                searchHighlight: true,
                searchBuilder: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                buttons: [{
                        text: '<i data-tooltip="true" title="განახლება" class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>',
                        className: 'btn-success',
                        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
                            table.state.clear();
                            update_operator_logs_personal(panel.id);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i data-tooltip="true" title="ბეჭვდა" class="fas fa-print"></i>',
                        className: 'btn-success',
                        extend: 'print',
                        title: 'printed_best_shop',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i data-tooltip="true" title="excel ფორმატი" class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>',
                        className: 'btn-success',
                        title: 'excel_best_shop',
                        extend: 'csv',
                        charset: 'UTF-16LE',
                        bom: true,
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i data-tooltip="true" title="დაკოპირება" class="fas fa-copy"></i>',
                        className: 'btn-success',
                        title: 'copied_best_shop',
                        extend: 'copy',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i data-tooltip="true" title="სვეტების გაფილტვრა" class="fas fa-eye"></i>',
                        className: 'btn-success',
                        title: 'filtered_best_shop',
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        columns: ':not(.noVis)'
                    }
                ],
                order: [
                    [2, 'desc'],
                    [2, 'asc']
                ],
                aoColumnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    aTargets: [0, 1]
                }],

                

            var info = table.page.info();
            var count = table.rows().count();

            $('#' + panel.id).find('.count-rows').html(count);

            table.buttons().container().appendTo($('#' + panel.id).find('#operatorLogs_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)'));
            
            table.searchBuilder.container().prependTo(table.table().container());
            
            
            table.columns.adjust();
```

The sequence of js files is as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.7/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.7/js/autoFill.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.4/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.3/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/2.6.2/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.3/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.8/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.4/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.1.0/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.1.0/js/searchBuilder.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.3.0/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script> <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/sorting/datetime-moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.1.0/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.1.0/js/searchBuilder.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code in your question appears to be incomplete or incorrectly copy/pasted. Also, if I build a basic DataTable using moment.js,, SearchBuilder, and the datetime sorting plug-in, then I cannot recreate your issue - everything appears to be working correctly.

Comment: One extra note: Use URLs with a protocol, wherever possible. For example, `src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/sorting/datetime-moment.js"` should be `src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/sorting/datetime-moment.js"`. See [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please, have a look at the JsFiddle example at https://jsfiddle.net/jL7pt01w/1/

Comment: Thank you for the Fiddle. I see that your Fiddle has a lot of duplicated/overlapping libraries - some in the HTML header, and others in the HTML body. I recommend you start again by using the official DataTables [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/), and then adding the extra libraries for the [datetime sorting add-on](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Operation).

Comment: It also looks as if you may have already reported this issue on the official [DataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/69420/cannot-use-date-filter-in-searchbuilder) - in which case, if your issue is resolved, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here.